# How to set keys for variables from radiabutton/select in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form with radio buttons and selects. 
How can I set each value of the radiobuttons/selects to a different key? 
I mean, the user has to select some option or radiobutton with value - "OPEN", and when I post data to the server I need to change it to "O", or "C" if value is "CLOSE", etc.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the presented text to be explicit (e.g "OPEN") and each matching value (that eventually will be posted to the server) to be implicit ("O" for "OPEN").

If that's the case, this is somewhat trivial - here's an example of radio buttons:

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="O"
           ng-model="myModel.state">
    OPEN
<label>

<label>
    <input type="radio" name="radioGroup" value="C"
           ng-model="myModel.state">
    CLOSED
<label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [AngularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select) for `select`. This well documented.

Define a list of possible values (names and IDs) in your controller:

```
$scope.departments = [
  {id: 100, name: "Development"},
  {id: 200, name: "Marketing"}
];
```

and define the select in your template:

```
<select ng-options="department.id as department.name for department in departments" ng-model="model.department">
  <option value="">Select Department ...</option>
</select>

<p>Selected department: {{model.department}}</p>
```